# Sprite editor "minimum size" feature alternative in Unity 5

Tags: unity, sprites

As you know , unity has been removed its `minimum size` feature in sprite editor multiple auto slice mode. In some pics Unity discovers a lot of tiny rubbish sprites for example as 4x3 or 10x5 pixels. Is there anyway to set minimum size for good auto slicing in [image]Unity 5?

Answer (score 1):

let me say that I don't know any way to set a minimum size. You might already know everything I'm telling you, but I figured I could try.

One way to "fix" it would be deleting those "wrong sprites" using CMD + delete if you're on a Mac (it *may* be only delete on Windows). Plus, is it possible that when creating the sprite in Photoshop/Krita/Gimp/Anything else you accidentaly drew a tiny line or point that you can't see but is still seen as sprite? It happened to me more than once. Just delete carefully around the shapes you want to keep.

Hope this can help even if I don't have a direct answer.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, but I'm looking for some automation inside Unity.